# Failed to install mono for android on windows 7

Tags: mono, windows-installer, xamarin.android

Heres the link to log http://pastebin.com/jqjhqjdR

It has downloaded about 750MB plus of data and still complaining. I have run setup.exe with administrator access too.

let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't have enough space available on the machine to install it. Here is a log extras:

> [Info] MSI (s) (88:E0) [14:37:14:059]: Product: Mono for Android 4.2.1 -- Disk full: Out of disk space -- Volume: 'C:'; required space: 7,17,101 KB; available space: 6,85,744 KB.  Free some disk space and retry.
>   [Info] Disk full: Out of disk space -- Volume: 'C:'; required space: 7,17,101 KB; available space: 6,85,744 KB.  Free some disk space and retry. [Info] Action ended 14:37:14: InstallValidate. Return value 3.

As a side note, to easily identify where a MSI failed, you can look the log for "value 3". If a standard action or custom action returns this value it means the installation was stopped. Of course if the log is generated in another language use the equivalent of the word "value" in that language.

Comment: thanx for the input, but it installed successfully after a restart - i did not create any more space, any clue?

Comment: maybe the restart triggered some cleaning operations in the OS that made more HHD space available, can't say for sure.